# window.location.hash not working in scribd document in firefox, opera

Tags: javascript, scribd

I have uploaded one [document on scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75580048/International-Conference-on-Excellence-in-the-Home-From-House-to-Home)

I have included links within the document for ease of navigation. It works fine when opened in Chrome, but not working well in Firefox 3.6.

It displays the the href path on the page in Firefox. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up looking for the hash character `#` in the `window.location.href` property and capturing the hash manually:

```
var hash = window.location.href.indexOf('#') == 
    -1 ? "" : window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1);
```